# How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged automatically

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527602/automatically-inotifypropertychanged)
>   [INotifyPropertyChanged and Auto-Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347309/inotifypropertychanged-and-auto-properties)

Currently I refactor an existing class in a WPF project to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged. The problem is that this class has around 150 members. So I have to write the following code for each members.

```
private string _member1;
...
public string Member1
{
    get { return _member1; }
    set { _member1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Member1"); }
}
```

It's a tiring and dull job. Is there a convenient way to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I have googled this type of question but failed to get a satisfactory answer. I need a simple, compile-time solution or a free toolkit. Thanks for providing the links.

Comment: Try this
http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/

Answer (score 4):

There`s a nice MSBuild task that does all that work for you - [Kind of Magic](http://kindofmagic.codeplex.com/). All you have to do is to add [Magic] attribute to a class and all of it`s properies will implement  change notification.

Comment: It's really what I wanted. Thanks very much.:)

Comment: That's a nice solution indeed