# Is it possible to override the Parameter keyword, or create a new Keyword, for observable properties?

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, observable

In VB.NET (without referencing 3rd-party libraries), I am finding that I am writing a lot of the following code:

```
Private _prop as String = "test"
Public Property Prop As String
  Get
    Return _prop
  End Get
  Set(value As String)
    _prop = value
    NotifyPropertyChanged()
  End Set

'(add more properties here...)

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Protected Overridable Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = "")
    If PropertyChangedEvent IsNot Nothing Then
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End If
End Sub
```

What I would like to be able to do is something like:

```
Public ObservableProperty Prop As String = "test"
```

and have ObservableProperty be a construct I define that does all the boilerplate stuff.

I know that if I didn't want it to be Observable, I could use that same pattern (`Public Property NonObsProp As String = "test"`), so is it possible to make them observable automatically also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to achieve automatic notification of property change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716400/simplest-way-to-achieve-automatic-notification-of-property-change)

Comment: The answers to that question use 3rd party libraries, which I want to avoid

Comment: Sadly, the answer to your question is no.  You're in good company though. Many of us wish for a simpler and built-in solution. (Have a look here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347309/inotifypropertychanged-and-auto-properties)

Comment: It was once proposed that properties be allowed to have `{Get, Set, Notify}` for such things, but MS declined.

Comment: @sstan, the `SetProperty` idea referenced in the link you put (by @crea7or) is great! It removes the boilerplate which is really useful, and I think the closest I'm going to get to an answer. If you want to write it up I'll give you the answer - otherwise I'll do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment from @sstan pointed me in the right direction. It's not a perfect answer, but it's the closest I'm going to get for now.

Essentially, it's the way referred to [here](http://danrigby.com/2012/04/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way-revisited/), which suggests creating a `SetProperty` method which calls `NotifyPropertyChanged`, cutting down on the boilerplate code.

Something like:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to cut down on the INPC property boilerplate, inspired by Knockout.js, would be to define an observable value type.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ObservableValue(Of T)
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanging As PropertyChangingEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanging.PropertyChanging
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Shared ReadOnly __changing As PropertyChangingEventArgs = New PropertyChangingEventArgs("Value")
    Private Shared ReadOnly __changed As PropertyChangedEventArgs = New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value")

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(initialValue As T)
        _value = initialValue
    End Sub

    Private _value As T
    Public Property Value As T
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(newValue As T)
            If Not EqualityComparer(Of T).Default.Equals(_value, newValue) Then
                RaiseValueChanging()
                _value = newValue
                RaiseValueChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub RaiseValueChanging()
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanging(Me, __changing)
    End Sub

    Public Sub RaiseValueChanged()
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, __changed)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return If(_value IsNot Nothing, _value.ToString(), String.Empty)
    End Function

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As T) As ObservableValue(Of T)
        Return New ObservableValue(Of T)(value)
    End Operator

End Class
```

This can then be used to define the properties - the class doesn't necessarily need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, unless that is needed for some other reason.

```vb
Public Class MyViewModel
    Public ReadOnly Property Prop1 As ObservableValue(Of String) = "A"
    Public ReadOnly Property Prop2 As ObservableValue(Of Boolean) = False
End Class
```

Then you need to remember to access the `.Value` property when getting/setting the value (the `ReadOnly` helps, and perhaps there is a more elegant way to expose the underlying value), e.g. in WPF bindings:

```vb
vm.Prop1.Value = "NewValue"
```

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop1.Value}"/>
```

I haven't used this pattern enough yet to discover the downsides... or even the upsides vs. the typical INPC patterns.